# Lateral Release

Tags: pronunciation, received-pronunciation

I am a EFL learner who focuses on RP. I have a question about lateral release of plosives t and d. I know that the release of t and d can be done by lowering the side of the tongue when t and d are followed by l, in cases like bottle and middle. And the l in such cases is a dark l, so the back of the tongue should be raised.

For example *bottle, title, middle,* and *noodle.*

My question is, during the closing and compression stage of the plosives t and d, should the back of the tongue be raised? Or can I keep the back of the tongue in the natural position, and only raise it during the release stage?

Thank you.

Comment: Eg are bottle, title, middle, noodle. Those words with a t/d followed by a dark l.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited them in to the question since comments can often get lost or overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think either results in any significant auditory difference, so my recommendation is to use whichever you find more comfortable. But given speech segments are produced very quickly and are co-articulated, the velarization most likely must take place during the closure of the preceding /t/ or /d/.